# How to edit a Row Content Wrapper in Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Please look at this page: https://escort.totevatravels.com/property/authentic-privat-townhouse/ and there you can see that the row with price on the top right goes to two lines. It looks ugly, right?

Now pres Ctrl+U and see its element.

If I change the two div(-s) with classes from

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

&

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

**TO**

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

&

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

it doesn't go to two lines and looks way better. Basically I just change the number of size from 9+3 to 7+5.

How do I change it in core theme? Like how can I find the file to change it for good? It's a Wordpress theme....

I am sorry for the way I describe it, it is like 4 am and I cannot think any more....

Cheers!

Looked for a specific page, asked support - nothing helped

Answer (score 0):

You will need to access to ftp to the site root, also to make a permanent change(won't be overwritten by theme updates) to a Wordpress Theme you'll need to create a child theme. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

To find a specific file it can be trial and error but I would try searching for classes of parent containers like .iw-heading-title it could be in header.php or maybe front-page.php or in a template part file inside an if(is_front_page()) every theme is different so there is no short answer.

I would suggest getting FTP set up and exploring the theme files to get familiar with your theme.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but couldn't find the file...I am just wondering if there is a way to find the file through the code or something...

Comment: Once you set up your ftp you should be able to search the theme files, the html code you see on the front end is generated by php so you can really get a clear idea of the code. Also your theme setting might allow you to adjust the width of column, like I say every them is different.

Answer (score -1):

first of all find that div you want to edit you can find it by right clicking on the specific section and select inspect element.

when you get the specific div you can see the class of that div or the id of that div, if hopefully you find that now go to customize option in WordPress theme it will show if you are login as admin in your website. we you open the customize option you will find at bottom (Add Additional CSS) here you will pass the class of id and change the styling etc from here . this is how you can change in the core theme

Comment: Nah, this is not how it works...I know how to find the specific element, but I cannot find the specific file that is needed to be changed (php, not css). Thanks for your message though!